# NodeJS 'appendFile' not creating file in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, appendfile

I have an application that creates a few CSV files in its working directory while it runs.  The application runs fine outside of my docker container, but when I run it within, I get an error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Data/Output.csv'
```

The file is written using the below function call in a myApp.js file.  I have tried using absolute/relative path and setting flags explicitly in the third parameter of appendFile.  Same error every time.

```
fs.appendFile('Data/Output.csv', Text, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
});
```

For debugging, I did a ***touch Output.csv*** and set the following line in my Dockerfile to see if the file is actually there, and below is the output of that.

```
Step 7/8 : RUN ls -al ~/myApp/src/Data
 ---> Running in 2dfabf2dd92b
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  7 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb  7 16:17 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  7 16:17 .gitkeep
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Feb  7 16:17 Output.csv
```

Yet when I ***docker run myApp/myApp*** I get the error that there is no such file or directory.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

#Install dependencies
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y git ssh nodejs npm gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

#install go and libraries
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz && <some git clones of private repos>

#clone from local repo    
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG SSH_CONFIG
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan <private repo> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 && echo "${SSH_CONFIG}" > ~/.ssh/config && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 && cd ~/ && git clone <private repo> && rm -rf ~/.ssh && touch ~/myApp/src/Data/Output.csv && chmod 777 ~/myApp/src/Data/Output.csv && cd ~/myApp/src && npm install

#CMD ["node", "root/myApp/src/myApp.js"]
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash #for debugging
```

Comment: Dockerfile declares steps of making container image.  Seems like Your code is creating file inside container (not image). So of course doing `ls -al` on build step will not show anything that You want.
Simply get inside docker container after running it: 1) `docker ps` find container id, 2) `docker exec -it CONTAINERIDHERE sh` to get inside container.

Comment: @num8er I did exactly that and the file is there.  Verified with both absolute and relative path to it too, but it won't find the file even if run it interactively from inside the container.

Comment: put Your Dockerfile to Your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WORKDIR` is not set properly for relative path to work as you expect it to work. 
Example of your Dockerfile with added `WORKDIR` and changed `CMD`.
(*Also check whether or not you have folder `Data` already created, if not it can also result in error*)

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y git ssh nodejs npm gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.13.7.linux-amd64.tar.gz && <some git clones of private repos>
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
ARG SSH_CONFIG
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && chmod 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan <private repo> ~/.ssh/known_hosts && echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 && echo "${SSH_CONFIG}" > ~/.ssh/config && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 && cd ~/ && git clone <private repo> && rm -rf ~/.ssh && touch ~/myApp/src/Data/Output.csv && chmod 777 ~/myApp/src/Data/Output.csv && cd ~/myApp/src && npm install
WORKDIR /root/src
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was part of the problem.  Another thing that I kept running into was trying to make a directory and cd into it in the same RUN command.  It worked when I separated them.

Comment: I’m glad I could help 